# please tell me how you set permission 777 on serverfree.com without SSH

Tags: permissions

anyone can please tell me  how you set permission 777 on serverfree.com because i am seen there and there is not any option to set permission and unable to set permission via web based ssh.

please tell me how you set permission.

actually everythis is fine on serverfree.com but i am unable to set cron, someone tell me it's permission issue , but i don't know how to set permission on serverfree.com without SSH ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you are able to set the permissions via your FTP-Client.
e.g. in FileZilla there is an option "File permissions..." where you can set the permission values for each file.

Comment: Thank's FTP permission system really work, i learned some this today, it's best for share hosting people which don't has SHH.

Answer (score 0):

You're on a *nix System, right?

If you only want set permissions without calling chmod directly(as your question suggests), you can try following on the console, if you have Perl installed:

```
perl -e 'chmod 0777, "Filename"'
```

---

Another approach is to use the `install` utility which is a glorified copying program which can set permissions in one step. (See the `-m` argument.)

```
install -m 777 "File" "/Copy/Location"
```

You can find it in the GNU coreutils(if you have it installed there), and isn't directly included to *nix systems(but BSD for example). Also simple move the file out of directory and call `install` to move it back.

But for both methods you need SSH, and i don't think there is a solution to set permissions without(because you never can do the `chmod()` system call that you need to set them).